# What is the problem with this lvalue error in ascending array?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char names[10][20] = { "kim", "lee", "sin", "jo", "kim2", "chae", "jin", "bak", "so", "choi" };

    int i, j;
    char tmp[20];

    printf("\nfirst\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        printf("%5s", names[j]);
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 9 - i; j++)
            if (strcmp(names[j], names[j + 1]) > 0)
            {
                //tmp = names[j];//
                //names[j] = names[j + 1];//
                //names[j + 1] = tmp;//
                //break;//
//This part.//
            }



    printf("\nSorted Result\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        printf("%5s", names[j]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I have to make this code without `strcpy`. but this code has l-value error. Any hints or suggestions to this problem?

Comment: Rather than use 2D array use an array of char pointers and just swap addresses

Comment: I successed an array.but i heard there is also 2d array way...

Comment: Sure you can do it with 2D array as well, but it involves copying strings, you can use `memcpy()` instead of `strcpy()` (but do not forget copy one byte extra for zero terminator) or roll your own `strcpy()`, but it is way less efficient than just swapping pointers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring tmp and names as array, use pointer, also because of break in for loop, it is not sorting all variables correctly.

Try with below program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *names[10] = { "kim", "lee", "sin", "jo", "kim2", "chae", "jin", "bak", "so", "choi" };

    int i, j;
    char *tmp;

    printf("\nfirst\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        printf("%5s", names[j]);
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 9 - i; j++)
            if (strcmp(names[j], names[j + 1]) > 0)
            {
                tmp = names[j];
                names[j] = names[j + 1];
                names[j + 1] = tmp;
            }

    printf("\nSorted Result\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        printf("%5s", names[j]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```